# How to show this 2d reprensentation of S3 is a representation and irreducible?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

[image]

I want to show that the representation above is actually a representation and is also irreducible. Since (12) and (123) are generators for S3, is it correct to say that all I need to do is to show that the order of $p(12)$ is the same as (12) and the order of $p(123)$ is the same as (123) as well as the following homomorphism: $p(12)(123)=p(12)p(123)$ and $p(123)(12)=p(123)p(12)$? I am not sure if this is sufficient and what the criteria are for showing a map as a representation given the generators.

As for the irreducibility of this representation, it should suffice to show there is no one-dimensional invariant subspace that satisfies the two matrices. Is that correct? We know the only invariant subspace of $p(12)$ is the span of (1,1) and (1,-1). However, since these are not invariant subspaces for $p(123)$, we have no invariant subspaces so this representation is irreducible.

Comment: You don't have a representation there. That map is only defined at two of the six elements of $S_3$. So, as a first step, you should extend it to a homomorphism from $S_3$ into $GL_2(\Bbb C)$. And *then* you check whether or not it is irreducible.

Comment: The elements $(12)$ and $(123)$ generate $S_3$, so of course you have a representation when you extend multiplicatively. (You can always define a homomorphisms on generators.) The key observation is that any nontrivial sub-representation must be 1-D AND invariant under the action of the generators. So, take an arbitrary $v=\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\end{pmatrix}$ and compute $p(12)v=\lambda v$ and $p(123)v=\mu v$ for scalars $\lambda,\mu\in \mathbb{{C}$ and try to solve the resulting system of equations. (You might want to prove $\lambda^2=1$ and $\mu^3=1$).